# Latex font typeface doesn't work

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, typefaces

I'm new to Latex and I'm trying to use it for my thesis. I want to use a font typeface for my document, so I follow the example from [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_typefaces).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tgbonum}

\begin{document}
This document is a sample document to test font 
families and font typefaces.

This text uses a different font typeface
\end{document}
```

However, it doesn't produce any pdf file. It throws the error:

```
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ec-qbkr): Font ec-qcsr at 600
not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If I remove the line \usepackage{tgbonum}, it creates a pdf with default font.

So how can I use another font for my document?

Comment: Did you install the package `tgbonum`?

Comment: hi, I think it is in the package named "tex-gyre" which is already installed in my laptop

Comment: Which distribution do you use?

Comment: I'm using Basictex2015 for Mac OS X, which is downloaded from https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html

Comment: On mac I'd recommend (a) installing the whole MacTex distro - it will save time in the long run (b) installing all the Tex Gyre fonts using Font Book (c) using xelatex and `fontspec` to load the fonts.

Comment: @Thruston It's only 5Gb left on my Mac so I couldn't install the whole version

Comment: @Bernard it said "command not found"

Comment: OK but you could still try parts (b) and (c).

Comment: @Lenhhoxung: I'm surprised you aren't having other problems if you only have 5GB space left on you HD. You may be able to use the TeX Live Utility to load the TeX Gyre fonts; but we are getting close to the release of TL2016/MacTeX-2016 which will make it more difficult to update.

Comment: If you are new to LaTeX and have no specific reason to use one flavour over another I would recommend using XeLaTeX as Thruston mentioned. 

It is usually a bit more straight forward than LaTeX. And for most parts XeLaTeX is backwards compatible with LaTeX.

Comment: XeLaTeX is the most problematic engine for me. It routinely sends my laptop into infinite loops, consuming system resources until I kill it from a(nother) terminal. I wouldn't recommend XeLaTeX unless you really need it. LuaLaTeX is much better behaved and has many of the same advantages, especially if security isn't too much of a concern. But a Mac will hate you with only 5G of space, unless it has changed *a lot*. This is a feature of the OS, I guess, as it isn't true for others. But it is for OS X.

Comment: Hm. Are you sure that your example gives this error?  `ec-qcsr` is TeX Gyre Schola and your document doesn't load it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're right, it is `ec-qbkr`. I've updated the question. I've tried all packages, some of them, for example `lmodern` and `times` worked, but others didn't.

Comment: `times` will definitely be installed and presumably `lmodern`. The TeX Gyre fonts are not basic, so those aren't installed by default if you choose a basic installation.

Comment: Maybe you might try using `upmap --sys`.